# Query registry value that contains slashes

Tags: batch, windows-registry, escape-characters

I am trying to grab the value of the registry key in serialcomm using this command:

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
```

which gives me:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM  
\Device\VCP0    REG_SZ    COM9                                                                                                                                                      
\Device\VCP1    REG_SZ    COM10
```

To get the data value COM9, I am running:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM" /v "\\Device\\VCP0"
```

but I get an error:

> ERROR: Invalid key name.
>      Type "REG QUERY /?" for usage.

What is the right way to search for the path `\Device\VCP0` so that the slashes are escaped correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the backslashes. However, The first part of your command is wrong. It contains redundant info. The correct command should be:

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM" /v "\Device\VCP0"
```